# javascript, XML, HTML, how to read xml in chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

how to read xml in chrome and firefox?
i have a code like this :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 
function showdata()  {       
    var xmldoc= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");         
    xmldoc.load("domxml.xml"); //this load domxml.xml file in my computer
    var error=xmldoc.parseError; 
    var total= 0;
    if(error!="")  { 
        document.write("Error, : "+error.reason); 
        return false;  } 
    else  {   
        var objPRODID=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODID"); 
        var objPRODNAME=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PRODNAME"); 
        var objPRICE=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PRICE"); 
        for(ctr=0;  ctr < objPRODID.length;  ctr++) { 
              var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
              var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
              var row = table.insertRow(x);
              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              cell1.innerHTML = objPRODNAME[ctr].text;
              cell2.innerHTML = objPRICE[ctr].text;   } 
       }      
} 
</SCRIPT> 

</HEAD>
<BODY onload="showdata()">
<table id="myTable" border="1"> 
  <tr>
     <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Price </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

this code is work only in IE
how to display the xml data in firefox and chrome browser??
help me please..

Comment: You can use XMLHTTPrequests to achieve this in none microsoft browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are using Microsoft/IE only non-standard code that won't work anywhere else. Things like ActiveX and MSXML are Microsoft products.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string you can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOMParser):

```
parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
```

If you want to load the XML from a URL, use the `responseXML` of [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest):

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () { /* use this.responseXML */ };
xhr.open("get", "file.xml", true);
xhr.send();
```